# C# led panel controlling over ethernet with native dll

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport, ethernet, led

Hy,

I had bought a "Huidu HD-E40" led panel a few days ago and the company sent me a .dll file. (I mean, it wasnt written in .Net). My question was the following: How can I use the file contents in C#. I had registered the dll via regsvr32, then added to the project reference but it seem like incompatible. I need some advice how to start with this projekt. I'd just like send a short string to the display via ethernet port. Sorry for my bad english, I'm a greenhorn from Hungary.

There are the file, that I've got for reference
http://wikisend.com/download/349890/Huidu_DLL_Reference1.doc

Comment: look up pinvoke on google

Comment: It seems to be suitable for this

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked more that 7 years ago, but for those who are looking for info on the SDK:

If you are referring to the HDSDK.dll which can be found in the Huidu_Gen6SDK_V1.9.zip then you need to use it with P/Invoke as that dll is not a .NET assembly but a native one. As @Kwang suggested if you would be able to download the SDK from their webpage there would be a complete C# demo.

Unfortunately it isn't available anymore, so you need to use the wayback machine to obtain it from here: https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://download.huidu.cn/download/*

Answer (score -2):

I think you need download the lastest version of HDSDK in the home page.It is contain some demo with C, C# and vb.net. Im using it for my project but it missed function create digit.